# Error while Integrate Third party framework for tvOS in XCODE 7.2

Tags: xcode7, tvos, tvos9.1

I am inegrating SFS2XAPI_tvOS framework for tvOS witn XCODE 7.2 and i am getting error "SFS2XAPI_tvOS/SmartFox2XClient.h File not Found" ,however framework in add in xcode .[image]